# Dragging the element but not dropping

Tags: javascript, selenium, drag-and-drop

While working on Selenium with JavaScript(Chrome Browser), Need to drag and drop an element.
With the below code, could able to drag but drop is not happening

```
await driver.actions({bridge:true}).dragAndDrop(source,destination).perform();
```

I've found some solutions in Java, however I am working on Selenium with JavaScript.

Answer (score 0):

try like this

```
driver.actions({bridge:true}).dragAndDrop(source,destination).build().perform();
```

Comment: Getting the belowerror: TypeError: driver.actions(...).dragAndDrop(...).build is not a function